# Replacement for obsolete iTextSharp HtmlUtilities?

Tags: .net, itext

Whenever I use `iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlUtilities.DecodeColor`, I get a validation warning saying that `HtmlUtilities is obsolete`. However, searching through the code over at https://github.com/itext/itextsharp I see that they are still using it in many places.

So, I am assuming that there is no replacement for this class. Is there one planned that anyone knows of or is there any other information that I should be aware of?

Comment: The static methods are probably generally safe to use going forward but if you are concerned about future compatibility you could bring those methods to your code. I believe the usage of `obsolete` was to keep on par with the Java version's deprecation of the entire `itextpdf.text.html` package which I think was a broad sweep to get users away from `HTMLWorker`. That specific method can actually be used natively in .Net via [Color.FromName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas. Unfortunately, `System.Drawing.Color.FromName` only works with named colors (like `"SlateBlue"`) whereas `iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlUtilities.DecodeColor` decodes both named colors as well as html style `"#AARRGGBB"` numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/HtmlUtilities.cs#L170) for `iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlUtilities.DecodeColor`:

```
public static BaseColor DecodeColor(String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;
    s = s.ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
    try {
        return WebColors.GetRGBColor(s);
    }
    catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can see that it is basically wraps a call to `WebColors.GetRGBColor`, [which is *not*](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/WebColors.cs#L243) marked as obsolete.

So, one good option is to just call `WebColors.GetRGBColor` directly in order to avoid the warning. Alternatively, you can wrap your call to DecodeColor in a pragma statement:

```
private static BaseColor GetBaseColor(string value)
{
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
    return iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlUtilities.DecodeColor(value);
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
}
```

Also, `WebColors.GetRGBColor` decodes named colors as well as html formatted color values (*e.g.* `#AARRGGBB`). If you only need named colors, you can use [System.Drawing.Color.FromName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx) as pointed about in the comments.

Comment: WebColors is now deprecated.